# ReactNative: UITableView.rectForRowAtIndexPath analog for ListView?

Tags: react-native

I need to find out position of item in the list view (like rectForRowAtIndexPath does for UITableView), how it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the built in onLayout function for a view. For instance:

```
 <View onLayout={this.handleLayout}/>
```

Then your function will have:

```
 handleLayout: function(event){
   var {x, y, width, height} = event.nativeEvent.layout;
   console.log('x pos:' + x + ' / y pos:' + y + ' / width:' + width + ' / height:' + height);
},
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Strange, it doesn't work well for several sections - it returns x,y _relative_ position to this parent view. Do you know how to receive absolute x,y ?

Comment: From what I know this will only read the parent view. Not sure if there is another method for that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this will work:

- make sure each item has unique ref prop (more about ref props in React documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html)
- in your code whenever you need call "measure" method on this.refs.your_reference. Make sure it is in componentDidMount(), however there might be a need to (Warning! Hacks!) to call it via setTimeout method as described here [React-Native : measure a View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29828971/react-native-measure-a-view)

Comment: Could you give code example? Even with setTimeout it doesn't work ("undefined is not an object (evaluating this.refs.itm0.measure), probably because refs are not available at that time?